# Cloud Storage state icons *replacement* inside the Sync Root folder

Tags: windows-runtime, icons, cloud, storage, c++-winrt

In relation to the blocked question at https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/SECURITY/ro-RO/74b81550-f2d9-47f5-af03-a44585119832/how-to-change-a-cloud-file-placeholders-status-icon?forum=windowssdk

> ```
> A call to ApplyCustomStateToPlaceholderFile() will set a new icon next to the existing one
> It does not replace an existing icon. Can we set a new custom icon, so there is only one icon is displayed?
> ```

```cpp
void Utilities::ApplyCustomStateToPlaceholderFile(PCWSTR path, PCWSTR filename, winrt::StorageProviderItemProperty& prop)
{
    try
    {
        std::wstring fullPath(path);
        fullPath.append(L"\\");
        fullPath.append(filename);

        auto customProperties{ winrt::single_threaded_vector<winrt::StorageProviderItemProperty>() };
        customProperties.Append(prop);
    
        winrt::IStorageItem item = winrt::StorageFile::GetFileFromPathAsync(fullPath).get();
        winrt::StorageProviderItemProperties::SetAsync(item, customProperties).get();
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        // winrt::to_hresult() will eat the exception if it is a result of winrt::check_hresult,
        // otherwise the exception will get rethrown and this method will crash out as it should
        wprintf(L"Failed to set custom state with %08x\n", static_cast<HRESULT>(winrt::to_hresult()));
    }
}
```

I prefer asking here instead of MSDN forums due to compulsory advertisement consent attached to their forum usage.

Comment: What's your question exactly?

Comment: @SimonMourier Can we set a new custom icon, so there is only one icon is displayed?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. You can't use a custom icon for this column. Only the one associated with the System.StorageProviderState property key enum. Explorer uses a combination of cloud file state (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/cfapi/ne-cfapi-cf_placeholder_state, especially CF_PLACEHOLDER_STATE_IN_SYNC) and file attributes (FILE_ATTRIBUTE_PINNED, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_UNPINNED). One thing I don't know is the error icon, I've never seen it in OneDrive and I don't know how to force OneDrive to show it somehow.

Comment: @SimonMourier That's exactly what I am talking about. The code above can add custom icons just fine to any state in that enumeration. Problem is how to remove the Windows / Explorer default icon associated with various states there.

Comment: You can't. The icon "Status" column (System.StorageProviderUIStatus) is displayed automatically by Explorer views using file system attributes and cloud placeholders state.

Comment: @SimonMourier Yeah... maybe some way to tell File explorer not to show the `status` column at all ?

Comment: The end-user can always remove the column but it doesn't seem its possible to remove it "permanently" https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/status-column-in-file-explorer-in-windows-10/b3b99f8c-c43c-4c3a-a652-93dc5befc51b

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. There is an [open PR](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/pull/154) demoing how to set the error icon using `PKEY_LastSyncError`.
2. After asked the question on MSDN forums(which seems I can't reply anymore), I found another way to achieve this:
   call [CfSetPinState](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/cfapi/nf-cfapi-cfsetpinstate) on the target file and pass in `CF_PIN_STATE_EXCLUDED`, this will exclude the file from syncing thus remove the existing icon, then apply your custom state on that file, there should be only your custom icon on the file now.

Comment: Are you the same who asked the question there on msdn forums ? Nice comeback, will check it out!

Comment: hey, setting `CF_PIN_STATE_EXCLUDED` still causes a synchronization icon to show up. That icon with two arching arrows. Any other steps to get rid of it ?

Comment: @kellogs are you setting `CF_PIN_STATE_EXCLUDED` on a dehydrated sparse placeholder file? try setting it on a folder or **hydrated** file. I'm not sure about the "arching arrows" icon(which seems to indicate that the file is compressed), I have not encountered this problem.